# Prevent array from changing index numbers when deleting items

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I have an array which gets filled within a for-loop:

```
var myArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < someOtherArray.length; i++)
{
    var element = someOtherArray[i];
    if (someCondition)
    {
         myArray[i] = element;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `myArray` gets filled with the indexes and contents from another array, but only if `someCondition` is true.

This results in an array like this, where not all indexes exists:

```
myArray = 
{
    [12] => 123, 
    [15] => 456, 
    [27] => 1789,
    [39] => 623,
}
```

If I now want to remove values > 1000 using `Array.splice()`:

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if (i in myArray) //check if index exists
    {
        if (myArray[i] > 1000)
        {
            myArray.splice(i, 1); //delete 1 Item, start at index i
        }
    }
}
```

In this loop the array entry `[27] => 1789` gets deleted, but the indexes higher than 27 decrement by 1:

```
myArray = 
{
    [12] => 123, 
    [15] => 456, 
    [38] => 623
}
```

How can i prevent JavaScript from decrementing those indexes? I really need them to stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `delete` instead of `splice`

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if (i in myArray) //check if index exists
    {
        if (myArray[i] > 1000)
        {
            delete myArray[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to say that XD

Comment: Strange... i never came across the delete operation although it is so obvious :) Thank you, totally solved my problem! will accept answer in 5 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set that particular index to `undefined` instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if (i in myArray) //check if index exists
    {
        if (myArray[i] > 1000)
        {
            myArray[i]=undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Array.filter of javascript :

```
var newArray  = array.filter(function(value) { 
     return value < 1000;
     })
```

Comment: mine you can use if want to get a list of valid value.